# How to get my loaded javascript code on server side?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm looking for a way to send the current loaded js code to the server to compare it with the original file using php.

For example, I include the test.js script in my html.
my test.js content :

```
function test() {alert('test')}
```

But imagine that someone tries to modify this code by using any web developer tool into

```
function test() {alert('cheat')}
```

So the code I want to send to my server is this one, then I could compare it in php and see if everything is fine, or not.
Can I get the js changed using web developer tool ?

I hope I'm clear enough.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: still the code send to the server could be faked as well :S

Comment: You should always sanitise and validate any user input - just in case someone does this.

Comment: Don't trust user input -- and i dont thing that you can access manipulated javascript code (via dev console changed). There is now way to get the changed code within javascript and send it via the enxt request to the server.

Comment: The user could just change the request that sends to the server as well.

Comment: There is no easy way of preventing content tampering and it usually isn't worth it

Comment: What you can do is: LazyLoad javascript functions just-in-time, so that an user can not manipulate an important function, because it is first loaded/reloaded when the given action is preformed.

Comment: You should study up on how browsers process script. Then you will realize your question makes no sense and that what you are asking can't be done

Comment: You might be able to use something like socket.io with node to be able to keep an open connection with the server. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it's an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Well I see, and of course charlie you're right, I asked it because may be I missed something..  I was hopping there was a solution, but like justonundermillions says, I could do lazyload, upgrade security on serverside by testing everything I can. The main purpose is to discourage users to cheat..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example (all in one file) how you can lazy load you original functions before using them.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['getjs'])){
    echo "myFunctions.test = function (){alert('test');}";
    exit;
}
?><html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // method/function holder
    var myFunctions = {};
    </script>
    <!-- load functions -->
    <script src="js.php?getjs=true"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    //original 
    myFunctions.test();//Alert:test
    //manipulation
    myFunctions.test = function (){alert('cheat');};
    myFunctions.test();//Alert:cheat
    //get original again, we use Math.random to prevent cache
    $.getScript('js.php?getjs=true&ui='+Math.random())
     .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
        //run original again
        myFunctions.test();//Alert:test
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- I use `obj methods` instead of `global functions`
- I use `$getScript()` to redefine the method before using it

So that can be a workaround to ensure that you are calling a function/method that works like you want. This only an option not an real solution, maybe an super-js-hacker can also get around this.